# Abort pending WMS image requests on map pan

Tags: geoserver, javascript, openlayers

Everytime there's a move in the map the OL3 requests a new image to the GeoServer ignoring the previous requests it has done which may lead to multiple pending image requests that are not going to be used.

Is there a way to abort these requests like in jQuery with .abort() for AJAX requests?

Answer (score 2):

No, once you've made a GetMap request the WMS service will do its best to respond to it.  You can't send an abort request.

Comment: Is there some way to provide a server side timeout to the requests? I seem to get loads queued up which then crash geoserver and tomcat and I have to reboot the whole PC :/

Comment: @dougajmcdonald You can change request timeouts in your web server software, not sure about GeoServer directly.